# How to process compressed data in Java

Tags: java, compression, gzip

I have some data which takes up more than 50MB in an uncompressed file, but compresses down to less than half a MB using `gzip`.

Most of this is numerical data.  I'm trying to figure out how to process this data without having to uncompress it completely.  For example, if this data contains a couple of strings and 5 or so numerical values per record, is there a way I can uncompress a single row (or a small set of rows), process them, then discard them?

Unix provides utilities such as `zcat`, `grep`, etc. which operate directly on compressed data, I'd like to do the same in Java.

Thanks

Comment: All gzip based Unix tools essentially uncompress the whole file when you work with the contents (except when piping to an application which finished without reading it all).  In other words they do not behave like you want your Java program to behave.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Which tools are you referring to? Most tools will uncompress on the fly unless you tell them to write the output to a file.

Answer (score 7):

Just wrap your `FileInputStream` in a `GZipInputStream`:

```
public static BufferedReader createReader (File f, String encoding) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream (f);
        if (f.getName ().endsWith (".gz"))
            in = new GZIPInputStream (in, 10240);

        return new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (in, encoding));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Missing encoding "+encoding, e);
    }
}
```